# How do I include screenshot in python pytest html report

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, pytest

When I hit the below url in browser "https://192.168.xx.xxx/Test/ScreenCapture"
I get the screenshot of the device screen under test in the browser.

How do I add the screenshot in my pytest html test report.
Currently I am using below code which captures screen shot in the test directory specified.

```
url = 'https://192.168.xx.xxx/Test/ScreenCapture'
driver.get(url)    driver.save_screenshot('/home/tests/screen.png')
```

I am running my pytest with below command : 
py.test --html=report.html --self-contained-html screentest.py

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html/: You can add details to the HTML reports by creating an ‘extra’

```
extra.image(image, mime_type='image/gif', extension='gif')
```

You need to make a hook.  Again from doc:

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
    if report.when == 'call':
        # always add url to report
        extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url('http://www.example.com/'))
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            # only add additional html on failure
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html('<div>Additional HTML</div>'))
        report.extra = extra
```

Comment: Where's the exact append image line in the hook code. Also you didn't mention the conftest.py file to be created.

Comment: everything is here: https://pytest-html.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#enhancing-reports

Comment: I tried the steps mentioned in the document. And it doesn't work. Your answer has the exact same code as the document. How is it supposed to help what the OP has asked?

Comment: if you really think the pytest-html documentation is wrong you should bring it up with them.

Answer (score 2):

I found one who found a solution by himself(@Vic152), here's the original post:https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html/issues/186
The key is to call `item.funcargs['request']` to get current test request context.

Note: if you use Pytest 3.0+ like me, replace `getfuncargvalue()` with `getfixturevalue()`

I copy the code here:

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):

    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S')

    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
    if report.when == 'call':

        feature_request = item.funcargs['request']

        driver = feature_request.getfuncargvalue('browser')
        driver.save_screenshot('D:/report/scr'+timestamp+'.png')

        extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image('D:/report/scr'+timestamp+'.png'))

        # always add url to report
        extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url('http://www.example.com/'))
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            # only add additional html on failure
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image('D:/report/scr.png'))
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html('<div>Additional HTML</div>'))
        report.extra = extra
```