# How to add screenshots to html reports generated by pytest-html plugin using selenium and pytest?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, pytest-html

I am trying to add screenshots of failed tests to html reports generated by pytest-html plugin,pytest libraries.I followed this [How do I include screenshot in python pytest html report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50534623/how-do-i-include-screenshot-in-python-pytest-html-report). However i always ended up with the below error.

**Error occuring:**

```
feature_request = item.funcargs['request']
KeyError: 'request'
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
import pytest_html

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S')
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
    if report.when == 'call':
        feature_request = item.funcargs['request']
        driver = feature_request.getfixturevalue('browser')
        driver.save_screenshot('Screenshots/scr' + timestamp + '.png')
        extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image('Screenshots/scr' + timestamp + '.png'))
        extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url('http://www.example.com/'))
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            # only add additional html on failure
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image('Screenshots/scr.png'))
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html('<div>Additional HTML</div>'))
        report.extra = extra

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def setup():
    print('Starting')
    url = 'https://www.google.com/'
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)
    return driver
```

**test_google.py**

```
class Test_One():
    def test_login(setup):
        print('Opend google')
        assert False
```

Whats wrong with my code ? how can i append screenshot on failed test cases ?

Answer (score 0):

you should have a fixture with request argument on your conftest.py, specifically your driver.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def setup(request):
```

```
then use driver = feature_request.getfixturevalue('setup') #referencing your def setup
```