# How can I add a screenshot in python pytest html

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, pytest-html

First of all I try the solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50534623/how-do-i-include-screenshot-in-python-pytest-html-report/69288815?noredirect=1#comment122466438_69288815)
I got this piece of code

```
import os
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver as selenium_webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'E:\Python Projects\StackField\testCases\chromedriver.exe')
    return driver

@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):

    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S')

    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
    if report.when == 'call':

        feature_request = item.funcargs['request']

        driver = feature_request.getfuncargvalue('browser')
        driver.save_screenshot('D:/report/scr'+timestamp+'.png')

        extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image('D:/report/scr'+timestamp+'.png'))

        # always add url to report
        extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url('http://www.example.com/'))
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            # only add additional html on failure
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.image('D:/report/scr.png'))
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html('<div>Additional HTML</div>'))
        report.extra = extra
```

When I run with this command:
pytest --html=report.html --self-contained-html testCases/test_basic.py

It returns me an internal error:
INTERNALERROR>     feature_request = item.funcargs['request']
INTERNALERROR> KeyError: 'request'

Then I tried this method:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("html")
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, "extra", [])
    if report.when == "call":
        # always add url to report
        extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url("https://sprint.moravis.com/run/val/adchef/a0bfkgb"))
        xfail = hasattr(report, "wasxfail")
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            # only add additional html on failure
            report_directory = os.path.dirname(item.config.option.htmlpath)
            # file_name = str(int(round(time.sleep() *1000)))+".png"
            file_name = report.nodeid.replace(": :", "_") + ".png"
            destinationFile = os.path.join(report_directory, file_name)
            driver.save_screenshot(destinationFile)
            if file_name:
                html = '<div><img src ="%s" alt="screenshot" style="width:300px:height=200px"'                       '\'onclick ="window.open(this.src)" align="right"/></div>' % file_name
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html(html))
        report.extra = extra


def pytest_html_report_title(report):
    report.title = "Stackfield report"
```

And I got this error:
INTERNALERROR>     driver.save_screenshot(destinationFile)
INTERNALERROR> NameError: name 'driver' is not defined

And from here I don't know how to continue.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make the driver in setup as global like

```
@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'E:\Python Projects\StackField\testCases\chromedriver.exe')
    return driver
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass fixtures to a hook.
What you need to do:

1. Call request fixture.
2. Call the fixture where the driver is initiated.

Should look like this:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("html")
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, "extra", [])
    if report.when == "call":
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            feature_request = item.funcargs["request"]
            driver = feature_request.getfixturevalue("setup")
            img_name = "name.png"
            img_path = os.path.join("path/to/image", img_name)
            driver.save_screenshot(img_path)
```