# generate html and json reports for selenium python automation test using pytest

Tags: json, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pytest, pytest-html

I have a selenium python automation test, it works fine, now I want to generate Html and JSON reports and have screenshots in the report using pytest. I am new to automation and python so I am not much aware of how its done.

following is my code

test_screenshot.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pytest_html
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidSessionIdException

def test_Openurl(setup):
    driver = setup["driver"]
    url = setup["url"]
    try:
        driver.get(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message)

    assert driver.current_url == URL
    driver.save_screenshot("ss.png")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    driver.save_screenshot("ss1.png")
    driver.close()
```

conftest.py

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--url", action="store", default="https://google.com/")

@pytest.fixture()
def setup(pytestconfig):
    s = Service("C:/Users/Yash/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe") 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
    driver.maximize_window()
    yield {"driver":driver, "url": pytestconfig.getoption("url")}
```

I ran this using

> pytest test_screenshot.py --url "https://www.netflix.com/in/"

Test case is passed. How do I generate HTML and JSON report?
I tried this

> pytest -v -s --json-report --json-report-indent=4 --json-report-file=report/report.json --html=report/report.html test_screenshot.py

but got this error

> ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
> pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --json-report --json-report-indent=4 --json-report-file=report/report.json
> inifile: None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install these two libraries : https://pypi.org/project/pytest-json-report/ & https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html/

Comment: hi yes thanks, but the screenshots are not included in the report. any idea how I can add those in it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50534623/how-do-i-include-screenshot-in-python-pytest-html-report

Answer (score 0):

Install this library for generating HTML report `pip install pytest-html`

Add the following two functions in conftest.py

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
    if report.when == 'call' or report.when == "setup":
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            file_name = report.nodeid.replace("::", "_") + ".png"
            _capture_screenshot(file_name)
            if file_name:
                html = '<div><img src="%s" alt="screenshot" style="width:304px;height:228px;" ' \
                       'onclick="window.open(this.src)" align="right"/></div>' % file_name
                extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html(html))
        report.extra = extra


def _capture_screenshot(name):
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(name)
```

This function will automatically take a screenshot when there is any failure occurs in the test case.

Execute the following command for generating the report

```
pytest -v -s --html=report.html
```